# Как вывести список файлов с ftp сервера в android приложении?

Tags: android, ftp

Как вывести список файлов с ftp сервера (а точнее из конкретной папки, лежащей на этом сервере) в android приложении?

Comment: подключите какую нибудь ftp4j и ознакомьтесь с документацией http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/manual.php

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться классами из библиотеки `org.apache.commons.net.ftp`. Подключение осуществляется классом `FTPClient`:

```
FTPClient mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
mFTPClient.connect(myAddress, myPort);
```

Подробный пример можете взглянуть [тут](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)